# deploy rails project from nitrous.io to Microsoft Azure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, nitrousio

I'm trying to deploy a rails project I've developed on Nitrous.io to Microsoft Azure.

I've followed the tutorials from [here:](http://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-ruby-deploy-capistrano-host-nginx-unicorn/) but it keeps failing when I run`bundle exec cap production deploy`

```
DEBUG[fa92be79] Running /usr/bin/env [ ! -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451 ] on myapp.cloudapp.net                                                                                                                                            
DEBUG[fa92be79] Command: [ ! -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451 ]                                                                                                                                                                                          
cap aborted!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host myapp.cloudapp.net: Authentication failed for user username@myapp.cloudapp.net                                                                                    
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:219:in `start'                                                                                                                                                                           
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'                                                                                                                                                      
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'                                                                                                                                          
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'                                                                                                                                                  
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `with_ssh'                                                                                                                                                          
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'                                                                                                                                                 
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'                                                                                                                                                               
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'                                                                                                                                                          
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:62:in `test'                                                                                                                                                               
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/capistrano-rbenv-2.0.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rbenv.rake:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'                                                                                                                   
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'                                                                                                                                                      
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'                                                                                                                                                                
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'                                                                                                                                       
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user username@myapp.cloudapp.net                                                                                                                                                    
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:219:in `start'                                                                                                                                                                           
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'                                                                                                                                                      
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'                                                                                                                                          
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'                                                                                                                                                  
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `with_ssh'                                                                                                                                                          
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'                                                                                                                                                 
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'                                                                                                                                                               
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'                                                                                                                                                          
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:62:in `test'                                                                                                                                                               
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/capistrano-rbenv-2.0.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rbenv.rake:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'                                                                                                                   
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'                                                                                                                                                      
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'                                                                                                                                                                
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => rbenv:validate                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Went and moved my development environment to an Ubunto vm on VirtualBox thinking it may have something to do with nitrous.io. But it's not. I'm now getting the same error on Ubuntu. Can anyone point me in the right direction?